# aborting after invariant() failure while starting mongos

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the below log when I try to start the mongos server. All mongod and config servers are running fine. I ran db.repairDatabase() in all mongo servers, but no luck till now. If anyone has a solution please let me know.

2020-03-30T13:52:22.239Z I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to 127.0.0.
1:27011 (1 connections now open to 127.0.0.1:27011 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-30T13:52:22.239Z I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to 127.0.0.
1:27012 (1 connections now open to 127.0.0.1:27012 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-30T13:52:23.236Z I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27016
2020-03-30T13:52:23.237Z I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to 127.
0.0.1:27016, took 1ms (1 connections now open to 127.0.0.1:27016)
2020-03-30T13:52:23.239Z I FTDC     [mongosMain] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with dire
ctory '/data/router1db/mongodb.diagnostic.data'
2020-03-30T13:52:23.241Z F -        [mongosMain] Invariant failure globalInShutdownDeprecated() src/mongo
/db/auth/user_cache_invalidator_job.cpp 120
2020-03-30T13:52:23.241Z F -        [mongosMain]

***aborting after invariant() failure

2020-03-30T13:52:23.243Z I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27015
2020-03-30T13:52:23.243Z I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to 127.
0.0.1:27015, took 0ms (1 connections now open to 127.0.0.1:27015)
2020-03-30T13:52:23.254Z F -        [mongosMain] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Comment: Are you running MongoDB 3.6 < 3.6.15? If so try upgrading to the latest 3.6.x release (3.6.17). I believe the fix for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-44184 may address this issue.

Comment: @JamesWahlin Thank you, I am using MongoDB 3.6. I will upgrade, let's see If the issue gets resolved.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so I can post the suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If encountered when running MongoDB 3.6, this is likely a bug reported by jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-44184. A minor release upgrade to 3.6.15 or greater will provide the fix.